# How to update list in React setState() method?

Tags: reactjs

Suppose, I have the following React component.

```
class Blog extends React.Component {
    state = { list: [] }

    addPost = () => {
        let postInfo = {
            authorName: document.getElementById('authorName').value,
            postTitle: document.getElementById('postTitle').value,
            postArea: document.getElementById('postArea').value,
        }

        let newList = [];
        newList.push(postInfo);

        this.setState({
           list: [this.state.list,...newList]
        })

        console.log(this.state.list);
        console.log(newList);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to My Blog</h1>
                <label>Enter Your Name</label> <br/>
                <input type="text" id="authorName"/> <br/>
                <label>Enter Post Title</label> <br/>
                <input type="text" id="postTitle"/> <br/>
                <label>Write Post</label> <br/>
                <textarea rows="4" cols="50" id="postArea"></textarea> <br/>
                <button onClick={this.addPost}>Add Post</button>
                <section id="blogArea"></section>
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

What I want is to input the respective fields with the appropriate data and then add them in an array of objects and then render the array as a table (I don't add this part here). But the problem is when I click the button and log the `this.state.list` data on the console, it shows the empty list.

I don't know what is the wrong with my code. How can I fix this and show the data in a proper way?

Comment: You are doing it in the wrong way

Comment: bor, we are supposed to use `document.getElementById()` in react. Its a bad practice.  You only have  a single form field, then why are you creating a list and pushing items to that.

Comment: So, what is the good practice here?

Comment: check my solution and the stackblitz example

Answer (score 4):

The way you implement is not recommended. I have updated the component. Please refer to the fiddle for working example [Check fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mx7ngq?file=Blog.js)

```
import React from 'react';
class Blog extends React.Component {
 initialForm={
   authorName:'',
  postTitle:'',
  postArea:'',
  id:1
 }
  constructor(){
    super();
    this.state = { 
      list:[
        this.initialForm
      ]
      }
    this.addPost = this.addPost.bind(this);
    this.setFormValue = this.setFormValue.bind(this);
    this.addForm = this.addForm.bind(this);
    this.removeForm = this.removeForm.bind(this);
  }

  addForm =() =>{
    const{list} = this.state;
    const form = {
      ...this.initialForm,
      id:Number(list[list.length -1].id) +1
    }
    list = [...list, form];
    this.setState({
      list
    })
  }

  addPost = () => {
    const {list} = this.state;
      console.log(list)
  }

  setFormValue = (e, index)=>{
    const {list} = this.state;
    list[index][e.target.name] = e.target.value
    this.setState({
      list
    })
  }

removeForm=index=>{
  const {list}= this.state;
  if(list.length > 1){
    list.splice(index, 1);
    this.setState({list})
  }
}

    render() {
          const {list} = this.state;
        return (
          <>
            <div>
                <h1>Welcome to My Blog</h1>
                {list && list.map((form, index)=>(
                  <div className="form-container" key={form.id}>
                  <span className="form-count">Form Id {form.id}</span>
                  <button type="button" className="form-remove" onClick={()=> this.removeForm(index)}></button>
                  <br />
                  <label>Enter Your Name</label> <br/>
                  <input type="text" name="authorName"  onChange={(e)=>this.setFormValue(e, index)}/> <br/>
                  <label>Enter Post Title</label> <br/>
                  <input type="text" name="postTitle" onChange={(e)=>this.setFormValue(e, index)}/> <br/>
                  <label>Write Post</label> <br/>
                  <textarea rows="4" cols="50" name="postArea" onChange={(e)=>this.setFormValue(e, index)}></textarea> <br/>

                  <section id="blogArea"></section>
                </div>
                ))}
            </div>

            <div>
            <br />
            <button onClick={this.addPost}>Add Post</button>

            <br />
            <button type="button" onClick={this.addForm}>Add Form</button>
            </div>
            </>
        )
    }
}

export default Blog
```

Comment: Thanks. I think this is a better implementation. But what if I want to add multiple posts one after another? That's why I used an array here.

Comment: If thats your question, I will update the code. Give me a min. :)

Comment: Also @ShahShishir Please mark it as correct answer if you find this better :)

Comment: Yeah, but I want to implement an extended version of this code.

Comment: @ShahShishir Please find the updated code in stackblitz,
https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-mx7ngq
I think now you can mark it as correct answe. :)

Comment: Thanks again. But the "Add Post" button doesn't work on your code. I don't know why!

Comment: @ShahShishir did you checked the console ??

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206916/discussion-between-shah-shishir-and-akhil-aravind).

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the spread operator to combine your arrays:

```
this.setState({
    list: [...this.state.list,...newList]
})
```

Comment: Also, no reason to create a `newList` array to add a new item.  Just put the new item in the list during setState, like this:  `this.setState({ list: [...this.state.list, postInfo] })`.